# How to format the time value in format 00:00:00 for a time column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, time

How to format the time value in format `00:00:00` i.e `hh:mm:ss` for a **time** column in SQL Server?

I have a scenario where in the time column the values are like

```
7:12:23
:1:23
:12:23
12:12:23
4:23
```

I want to format them as

```
07:12:23
00:01:23
00:12:23
12:12:23
00:04:23
```

I tried to do but not able to achieve the format as `00:00:00` in all. Thanks.

Comment: What, of the many, functions SQL Server provides (cast/convert/format), have you tried?

Comment: Sounds you have varchar column **pretending** to be a time column. You should fix that, first (because if this is true it really is **broken** right now), and then suddenly the solution becomes easy.

Comment: If you store the ttime value in a time data type column as you should, `FORMAT(YourTimeColumn,'hh\:mm\:ss')`.

Comment: i am getting this data from excel sheet which is dump into  SQL Server with SSIS,And some of the column value in excel file  are like `:00:20` i.e colon is appended at first in some values.

Comment: `time` doesn't have a format, it's a binary value. It's up to your presentation layer to determine the **displayed** format. If you have data in years it database that looks like `'
:12:23'` it's not a `time`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TimeFromParts()` in concert with `ParseName()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('7:12:23')
,(':1:23')
,(':12:23')
,('12:12:23')
,('4:23')
 
Select SomeCol
      ,AsTime = TimeFromParts(
                              IsNull(parsename(S,3),0)
                             ,IsNull(parsename(S,2),0)
                             ,IsNull(parsename(S,1),0)
                             ,0
                             ,0
                             )
 From @YourTable
 Cross Apply ( values ( replace(SomeCol,':','.') ) ) B(S)
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol     AsTime
7:12:23     07:12:23
:1:23       00:01:23
:12:23      00:12:23
12:12:23    12:12:23
4:23        00:04:23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try_cast and try_convert are convenient in these situations because they'll return NULL value(s) if the conversion is not successful.  The sample data fails where the first character is ':'.  In those cases this code pre-pends '00' and then the conversions succeed.

```
declare @YourTable      table ([SomeCol] varchar(50));

insert into @YourTable values 
 ('7:12:23')
,(':1:23')
,(':12:23')
,('12:12:23')
,('4:23');

select try_cast(case when charindex(':', SomeCol)=1
                     then concat('00', SomeCol)
                     else SomeCol end as time) 
from @YourTable;
```

Output

```
(No column name)
07:12:23.0000000
00:01:23.0000000
00:12:23.0000000
12:12:23.0000000
04:23:00.0000000
```

To output an 8 character formatted string

```
select convert(char(8), t.sc_time, 8) formatted_time
from @YourTable
     cross apply (values (try_cast(case when charindex(':', SomeCol)=1
                                        then concat('00', SomeCol)
                                        else SomeCol end as time))) t(sc_time);
```

Output

```
formatted_time
07:12:23
00:01:23
00:12:23
12:12:23
04:23:00
```